# How to compute total time from two separated object keys in Vue js?

Tags: database, vue.js, foreach, reduce, computed-properties

I'm expecting to compute total time by subtracting date and time from separated object keys in the data array. Hense I'm having a static start and end date format 'yy-mm-dd' and time format '01:02:30'. And I need to compute its time difference. But I'm not sure if the syntax is ok.

```js
data (
  return {
  shifts: [
    {
      id: '1',
      start_date: '2022-04-23',
      start_time: '19:32:00',
      end_date: '2022-05-23',
      end_time: '07:32:00'
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      start_date: '2022-04-23',
      start_time: '19:32:00',
      end_date: '2022-05-23',
      end_time: '07:32:00'
    }
    ]
  }
)

computed: {
totalShiftTime () {
    return this.shifts.forEach(t => (t.end_date + t.start_time) - (t.end_date + t.start_time))
    // expecting to return smth like 11:12:32 format // means total time
    }
}
```